# Why isn't it removing the duplicates from a Sheets Column?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I'm retriving the values from a column, where we have many duplicates. The goal is to keep only the unique values, but none of the methods I've tried has worked.

Here's what I've tried:

```
function listaProdutos() {
  const ssBDCadProd = SpreadsheetApp.openById(CAD_PRODUTO);
  const sheetBDCadProd = ssBDCadProd.getSheetByName('CadProduto');
  let listaProd = sheetBDCadProd.getRange(2, 6, sheetBDCadProd.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  let uniques = [...new Set(listaProd)];
  Logger.log('Únicos: ' + uniques);
}
```

Here's another attempt:

```
function listaProdutos() {
  const ssBDCadProd = SpreadsheetApp.openById(CAD_PRODUTO);
  const sheetBDCadProd = ssBDCadProd.getSheetByName('CadProduto');
  let listaProd = sheetBDCadProd.getRange(2, 6, sheetBDCadProd.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  let uniques = removeDups(listaProd);
  Logger.log('Únicos: ' + uniques);
}

function removeDups(array) {
  var outArray = [];
  array.sort();
  outArray.push(array[0]);
  for (var n in array) {
    Logger.log(outArray[outArray.length - 1] + '  =  ' + array[n] + ' ?');
    if (outArray[outArray.length - 1] != array[n]) {
      outArray.push(array[n]);
    }
  }
  return outArray;
}
```

All of them log the values repeatedly and I'm not sure if I'm missing any implicit characteristics of how the data comes in with `getValues()`

Thank you!

Comment: Your `listaProdutos()` function does not return anything; it cannot affect anything else.

Comment: Hi, @Pointy! I was using globals for retriving files/origin of data. For the time being, I'm logging ```uniques```, but values are coming repeatedly.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, `let listaProd = sheetBDCadProd.getRange(2, 6, sheetBDCadProd.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();` is the 2 dimensional array like `[["f2"],["f3"],,,]`. In this case, `[...new Set(listaProd)]` cannot remove the duplicated rows. When you want to remove the duplicated rows, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
let uniques = [...new Set(listaProd)];
```

##### To:

```
let uniques = [...new Set(listaProd.map(([f]) => f))];
```

This returns 1-dimensional array. When you want to return the 2-dimensional array, please use the following modification.

```
let uniques = [...new Set(listaProd.map(([f]) => f))].map(f => [f]);
```

#### Note:

- In the case of `Logger.log('Únicos: ' + uniques);`, even when `uniques` is a 2-dimensional array, the value of the comma-separated value like `f2,f3,,,,` is shown. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also, you can use `let uniques = [...new Set(listaProd.flat())];`. But in this case, the process cost becomes higher than that of the use of the destructuring assignment. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/10/23/benchmark-process-costs-for-retrieving-values-from-arrays-for-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/) So, in this answer, I proposed the method using the destructuring assignment.

Comment: This is superb! Thank you!